# Unable to send data from node server to ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

In my server file I am trying to send over data from a txt file and receive it in ajax like so

```
app.get('/send', function(req, res) {
showData = fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  res.send({data:data})
  })
})
```

It reaches my ajax code and I want to append it to my html but I am unable to

```
console.log(response.data)
            response.data.forEach(function(val) {
                console.log(val.id)
                tbodyEl.append('\
                    <tr>\
                        <th class="id">' + val.id + '</th>\
                    </tr>\
                    ')
            })
```

When I send through just a normal json variable from my server file it works but when I try use the text file it doesn't (saying TypeError: response.data.forEach is not a function )

Comment: Why are you using `forEach`?

Comment: because I want to loop through each json object and append it

Comment: "Each json" object? You're only receiving one, `data`, and it just contains a `string`..

Comment: I mean I want to append the values from inside the json object but thought that I need to loop through them in order to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the code you've included => `response.dataata`.

You also need to `JSON.parse()` the response data.

Assuming that the code you're running is typo-free and the response has been parsed, the other issue you could be facing is that the file contains invalid JSON or does not contain an Array.

Comment: Corrected typo, the response is parsed in the server.js, does it need to be parsed in the ajax script as well?

Comment: The code you've included here does not parse the file on the server (and I wouldn't. `JSON.parse()` blocks the event loop in Node). But the answer is yes, it needs to be parsed on the client before you can `forEach` over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep forEach on the Ajax side, an alternative solution is to change `res.send({data:data})` to `res.send(data)`. Assuming that data is an array, you can then parse on the Ajax side with `JSON.parse(response).forEach(...)`